# What is the correct way of reading from a TCP socket in C/C++?

Tags: c++, c, tcp

Here's my code:

```
// Not all headers are relevant to the code snippet.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>
#include <unistd.h>

char *buffer;
stringstream readStream;
bool readData = true;

while (readData)
{
    cout << "Receiving chunk... ";

    // Read a bit at a time, eventually "end" string will be received.
    bzero(buffer, BUFFER_SIZE);
    int readResult = read(socketFileDescriptor, buffer, BUFFER_SIZE);
    if (readResult < 0)
    {
        THROW_VIMRID_EX("Could not read from socket.");
    }

    // Concatenate the received data to the existing data.
    readStream << buffer;

    // Continue reading while end is not found.
    readData = readStream.str().find("end;") == string::npos;

    cout << "Done (length: " << readStream.str().length() << ")" << endl;
}
```

It's a little bit of C and C++ as you can tell. The BUFFER_SIZE is 256 - should I just increase the size? If so, what to? Does it matter?

I know that if "end" is not received for what ever reason, this will be an endless loop, which is bad - so if you could suggest a better way, please also do so.

Comment: Thank your for your contribution. Please note that my code implements the read() method, which can be found in the sys/socket.h library, which is "part of the GNU C Library" and not the C++ library.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Without knowing your full application it is hard to say what the best way to approach the problem is, but a common technique is to use a header which starts with a fixed length field, which denotes the length of the rest of your message.

Assume that your header consist only of a 4 byte integer which denotes the length of the rest of your message. Then simply do the following.

```
// This assumes buffer is at least x bytes long,
// and that the socket is blocking.
void ReadXBytes(int socket, unsigned int x, void* buffer)
{
    int bytesRead = 0;
    int result;
    while (bytesRead < x)
    {
        result = read(socket, buffer + bytesRead, x - bytesRead);
        if (result < 1 )
        {
            // Throw your error.
        }

        bytesRead += result;
    }
}
```

Then later in the code

```
unsigned int length = 0;
char* buffer = 0;
// we assume that sizeof(length) will return 4 here.
ReadXBytes(socketFileDescriptor, sizeof(length), (void*)(&length));
buffer = new char[length];
ReadXBytes(socketFileDescriptor, length, (void*)buffer);

// Then process the data as needed.

delete [] buffer;
```

This makes a few assumptions:

- ints are the same size on the sender and receiver.
- Endianess is the same on both the sender and receiver.
- You have control of the protocol on both sides
- When you send a message you can calculate the length up front.

Since it is common to want to explicitly know the size of the integer you are sending across the network define them in a header file and use them explicitly such as:

```
// These typedefs will vary across different platforms
// such as linux, win32, OS/X etc, but the idea
// is that a Int8 is always 8 bits, and a UInt32 is always
// 32 bits regardless of the platform you are on.
// These vary from compiler to compiler, so you have to 
// look them up in the compiler documentation.
typedef char Int8;
typedef short int Int16;
typedef int Int32;

typedef unsigned char UInt8;
typedef unsigned short int UInt16;
typedef unsigned int UInt32;
```

This would change the above to:

```
UInt32 length = 0;
char* buffer = 0;

ReadXBytes(socketFileDescriptor, sizeof(length), (void*)(&length));
buffer = new char[length];
ReadXBytes(socketFileDescriptor, length, (void*)buffer);

// process

delete [] buffer;
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Ori Pessach's comment is a good complimentary answer to this one.

Comment: late to the party, but as you don't know the Endianess of the other side of the communication, length should probably be in network byte order, so in your example: 
`ReadXBytes(socketFileDescriptor, sizeof(length), (void*)(&length));
length=::ntohl(length); buffer = new char[length];
ReadXBytes(socketFileDescriptor, length, (void*)buffer);`

Answer (score 11):

Several pointers:

You need to handle a return value of 0, which tells you that the remote host closed the socket.

For nonblocking sockets, you also need to check an error return value (-1) and make sure that errno isn't EINPROGRESS, which is expected.

You definitely need better error handling - you're potentially leaking the buffer pointed to by 'buffer'. Which, I noticed, you don't allocate anywhere in this code snippet.

Someone else made a good point about how your buffer isn't a null terminated C string if your read() fills the entire buffer. That is indeed a problem, and a serious one.

Your buffer size is a bit small, but should work as long as you don't try to read more than 256 bytes, or whatever you allocate for it.

If you're worried about getting into an infinite loop when the remote host sends you a malformed message (a potential denial of service attack) then you should use select() with a timeout on the socket to check for readability, and only read if data is available, and bail out if select() times out.

Something like this might work for you:

```
fd_set read_set;
struct timeval timeout;

timeout.tv_sec = 60; // Time out after a minute
timeout.tv_usec = 0;

FD_ZERO(&read_set);
FD_SET(socketFileDescriptor, &read_set);

int r=select(socketFileDescriptor+1, &read_set, NULL, NULL, &timeout);

if( r<0 ) {
    // Handle the error
}

if( r==0 ) {
    // Timeout - handle that. You could try waiting again, close the socket...
}

if( r>0 ) {
    // The socket is ready for reading - call read() on it.
}
```

Depending on the volume of data you expect to receive, the way you scan the entire message repeatedly for the "end;" token is very inefficient. This is better done with a state machine (the states being 'e'->'n'->'d'->';') so that you only look at each incoming character once.

And seriously, you should consider finding a library to do all this for you. It's not easy getting it right.

Comment: Not EINPROGRESS. EAGAIN or EWOULDBLOCK.

Answer (score 5):

If you actually create the buffer as per dirks suggestion, then:

```
  int readResult = read(socketFileDescriptor, buffer, BUFFER_SIZE);
```

may completely fill the buffer, possibly overwriting the terminating zero character which you depend on when extracting to a stringstream. You need:

```
  int readResult = read(socketFileDescriptor, buffer, BUFFER_SIZE - 1 );
```

Answer (score 3):

1) Others (especially dirkgently) have noted that buffer needs to be allocated some memory space.  For smallish values of N (say, N <= 4096), you can also allocate it on the stack:

```
#define BUFFER_SIZE 4096
char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE]
```

This saves you the worry of ensuring that you `delete[]` the buffer should an exception be thrown.

But remember that stacks *are* finite in size (so are heaps, but stacks are finiter), so you don't want to put too much there.

2) On a -1 return code, you should not simply return immediately (throwing an exception immediately is even more sketchy.)  There are certain normal conditions that you need to handle, if your code is to be anything more than a short homework assignment. For example, EAGAIN may be returned in errno if no data is currently available on a non-blocking socket. Have a look at the man page for read(2).

Comment: Good point, its not good to leave open socket handles lying around; will consider throwing afterward.

Comment: Actually, I didn't address the open socket handle, because it's not opened in the snippet that you posted. But I'm glad you thought of it :-)

Answer (score 2):

Where are you allocating memory for your `buffer`? The line where you invoke `bzero` invokes undefined behavior since buffer does not point to any valid region of memory.

```
char *buffer = new char[ BUFFER_SIZE ];
// do processing

// don't forget to release
delete[] buffer;
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an article that I always refer to when working with sockets..

[THE WORLD OF SELECT()](http://www.lowtek.com/sockets/select.html)

It will show you how to reliably use 'select()' and contains some other useful links at the bottom for further info on sockets.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to things from several of the posts above:

read() -- at least on my system -- returns ssize_t. This is like size_t, except is signed. On my system, it's a long, not an int. You might get compiler warnings if you use int, depending on your system, your compiler, and what warnings you have turned on.

Answer (score 0):

For any non-trivial application (I.E. the application must receive and handle different kinds of messages with different lengths), the solution to your particular problem isn't necessarily just a programming solution - it's a convention, I.E. a protocol.

In order to determine how many bytes you should pass to your `read` call, you should establish a common prefix, or header, that your application receives. That way, when a socket first has reads available, you can make decisions about what to expect.

A binary example might look like this:

```cpp
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

enum MessageType {
    MESSAGE_FOO,
    MESSAGE_BAR,
};

struct MessageHeader {
    uint32_t type;
    uint32_t length;
};

/**
 * Attempts to continue reading a `socket` until `bytes` number
 * of bytes are read. Returns truthy on success, falsy on failure.
 *
 * Similar to @grieve's ReadXBytes.
 */
int readExpected(int socket, void *destination, size_t bytes)
{
    /*
    * Can't increment a void pointer, as incrementing
    * is done by the width of the pointed-to type -
    * and void doesn't have a width
    *
    * You can in GCC but it's not very portable
    */
    char *destinationBytes = destination;
    while (bytes) {
        ssize_t readBytes = read(socket, destinationBytes, bytes);
        if (readBytes < 1)
            return 0;
        destinationBytes += readBytes;
        bytes -= readBytes;
    }
    return 1;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int selectedFd;

    // use `select` or `poll` to wait on sockets
    // received a message on `selectedFd`, start reading

    char *fooMessage;
    struct {
        uint32_t a;
        uint32_t b;
    } barMessage;

    struct MessageHeader received;
    if (!readExpected (selectedFd, &received, sizeof(received))) {
        // handle error
    }
    // handle network/host byte order differences maybe
    received.type = ntohl(received.type);
    received.length = ntohl(received.length);

    switch (received.type) {
        case MESSAGE_FOO:
            // "foo" sends an ASCII string or something
            fooMessage = calloc(received.length + 1, 1);
            if (readExpected (selectedFd, fooMessage, received.length))
                puts(fooMessage);
            free(fooMessage);
            break;
        case MESSAGE_BAR:
            // "bar" sends a message of a fixed size
            if (readExpected (selectedFd, &barMessage, sizeof(barMessage))) {
                barMessage.a = ntohl(barMessage.a);
                barMessage.b = ntohl(barMessage.b);
                printf("a + b = %d\n", barMessage.a + barMessage.b);
            }
            break;
        default:
            puts("Malformed type received");
            // kick the client out probably
    }
}
```

You can likely already see one disadvantage of using a binary format - for each attribute greater than a `char` you read, you will have to ensure its byte order is correct using the `ntohl` or `ntohs` functions.

An alternative is to use byte-encoded messages, such as simple ASCII or UTF-8 strings, which avoid byte-order issues entirely but require extra effort to parse and validate.

There are two final considerations for network data in C.

The first is that some C types do not have fixed widths. For example, the humble `int` is defined as the word size of the processor, so 32 bit processors will produce 32 bit `int`s, while 64 bit processors will produces 64 bit `int`s. Good, portable code should have network data use fixed-width types, like those defined in `stdint.h`.

The second is struct padding. A struct with different-widthed members will add data in between some members to maintain memory alignment, making the struct faster to use in the program but sometimes producing confusing results.

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main()
{
    struct A {
        char a;
        uint32_t b;
    } A;

    printf("sizeof(A): %ld\n", sizeof(A));
}
```

In this example, its actual width won't be 1 `char` + 4 `uint32_t` = 5 bytes, it'll be 8:

```
mharrison@mharrison-KATANA:~$ gcc -o padding padding.c
mharrison@mharrison-KATANA:~$ ./padding 
sizeof(A): 8
```

This is because 3 bytes are added after `char a` to make sure `uint32_t b` is memory-aligned.

So if you `write` a `struct A`, then attempt to read a `char` and a `uint32_t` on the other side, you'll get `char a`, and a uint32_t where the first three bytes are garbage and the last byte is the *first* byte of the actual integer you wrote.

Either document your data format explicitly as C struct types or, better yet, document any padding bytes they might contain.

Comment: Come on now. I wrote ReadXBytes, not Duncan. ;) Seriously though your ReadExpected will overwrite the front of the destination buffer if you have more than one read, since you are not offsetting by what you already read in from the socket.
Also if the MessageHeader struct is not single byte aligned you may be reading in more than you intended. It would have to match the byte alignment of the sender.

Comment: That's embarrassing, sorry for the mis-attribution. I swear I've written networking code, experienced that problem and fixed it before, I just forgot about it this time.

On the one hand, if you're using a custom binary message format I would assume you're using the same library client- and server-side for data representation, so stuff like struct padding ends up shared. On the other, taking into account different compilers, platform endianness, interoperability with custom clients...

This is probably why many people just use byte strings.

Comment: I _also_ just remembered that the C standard doesn't specify a standard size for enums, so the enum's size could change depending on how many values it contains... or which compiler you're using.

Trying to focus on the point of the answer without sweating a lot of the details is a tough task.