# Reading live stream data from a terminal host

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, stream

I am using a terminal as a host to input data (via copy/paste an arbitrary set of characters into the terminal). I want to capture this stream of data in my application.

I am using [this code sample](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/multipage/clientserver.html#simpleclient) as a client to listen to the host. However, the output I receive is a small string, not equal to the size of the buffer. I anticipated the code to print out the string, equal to the size of the buffer.

```
> buffer size = 100;
> --
> sample input (copy/pasted into terminal): "here is a random string" 
>
> current output: "h" 
> expected output: "here is a random string"
```

How would I capture this "live" stream of data and have output consistent with the buffer, instead of a small string?

Comment: Does `freeaddrinfo()` before calling  `recv()` have a bad effect?

Comment: @ryyker See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19103955/1121302). I was relying on `recv()` to gather **all** data.

Comment: Thanks.  Don't forget to mark your answer as _answered_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some investigation, the `recv()` function is not guaranteed to gather **all** data I want.

To do this, I followed: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12696176/1121302

Now, I get my expected output.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like they are using the UDP protocol and not TCP which guarantees the delivery and order. Even the page you linked mentioned this half way down the page.

> Remember: data sent using UDP datagram sockets isn't guaranteed to arrive!

Comment: ***[More](http://www.microhowto.info/howto/listen_for_and_receive_udp_datagrams_in_c.html)*** on the topic.